# devise_token_auth - is it possible to authenticate_user! without failing the filter chain?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, token

I have an API that needs to return results based on whether there is a signed in user or not. I'm using [devise_token_auth](https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth) on the rails side, and ng_token_auth on the client side (Angular).

In my controller, I would like to do something like the following:

1. Try to authenticate_user, but don't fail the filter chain if authentication failed.
2. Use current_user when creating the response payload (current_user will either contain nil or the authenticated user).

Take this code for example:

```
class Api::MyController < Api::ApiController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!

  def index
    if current_user
      # Create the result json using current_user
    else
      # Create the result json without user data
    end

    render json: result
  end
end
```

Only authenticated users will pass the authenticate_user! call and get to the index method. **I'd like** all users to get there, both authenticated and non-authenticated.

Answer (score 1):

You could try the following (not tested because I currently don't have Rails installed).

```
skip_before_filter :authenticate_user!, only: [:index_auth_failed]

before_filter do
  authenticate_user! rescue redirect_to index_auth_failed
end

def index
   # current_user exists
end

def index_auth_failed
   # current_user does not exist
end
```

Comment: Nice idea! I thought it would work but seems like it doesn't get to the rescue block when authentication fails (I added a breakpoint there and it never reached it)..

Comment: You could try to follow [this article](http://codebeerstartups.com/2013/01/custom-redirect-after-login-fail-in-devise/) and redirect to `index_auth_failed` if the authentication fail, but then all of your controllers's actions will redirect to this one when authentication needed, I don't know if that's what you want !